# Excel calculation in one cell result in another

Tags: excel

Hello I'm wondering is it possible to have the calculation in one cell and the result in another so that when the calculation is changed it automatically changes the result in the other cell.

E.g 
A1 = (2*3*4)*5

B1 = Result of calculation

[image: Example [EXCEL SHEET][1]]

As mentioned, i would like it when the calculation is changed in the specific cell it will automatically adjust the result in the other cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I know of is to use VBA.

```
Function CustomEval(ByVal formula As String) As Double
    CustomEval = Evaluate(formula)
End Function
```

This function will allow you to do something like this:

[image: CustomEval]

Comment: No problem! Take a look at the [evaluate documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) if you'd like further details.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how Excel works. What you call a "calculation" is really just a mix of numbers and symbols, which Excel regards as text.

Instead of putting text with a mix of symbols and numbers into a cell, you'd typically enter the number values into individual cells, then enter a formula into the cell where you want to see the result. That formula will reference the input cells. Example below.

[image]

Now you can change the values in the columns A, B, C and D and the result in column F will re-calculate.

What you describe can be achieved with the help of a named formula that you insert with Formulas > Name Manager > New then enter this formula into the Refers to field

```
=EVALUATE(Sheet1!$A$1)
```

Then enter the named range into a cell like in this screenshot

[image]

But then again, if you enter a "calculation" like `(2*3*4)*5` into a cell, you might as well put a `=` sign in front of it and there is your result.

Comment: Thanks! I mean i know your way perfectly well but i was wondering could it be done like this because i have a large amount of various calculations, some with more multiples, some with less so it would mean having to create a different formula for each type of calculation which would take up too much time.

Comment: I added a few suggestions.

Comment: You **do** know that you can copy and paste a formula, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your suggestions they were great help but for my task i think VBA is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I rarely post a second answer, but this is a different approach without VBA.

With **Excel 2013 and higher** you can turn the thing around. Enter the full calculation formula in column B, starting with a = sign, so it is an Excel formula.

Then use the function Formulatext() in column A to display what is being calculated. Strip out the `=` sign with Substitute() if it is not wanted.

[image]

The formula in A2 is

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(B2),"=","")
```

... copied down.

Benefit: Runs on any platform. Mobile, Web, iPad, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a real messy solution, but i'm often in the same predicament as you.  This requires 3 steps of human input, but can be mass applied.
1: use concatenate function to display your formula including = (equals sign) and an additional character before the = (equals sign); I'll explane the additional character latter.
[use concatenate function to display your formula including = (equals sign) and an additional character before the = (equals sign); I'll explane the additional character latter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vce1A.png)
2: copy and paste values only to the cell you want the answer to be shown
[copy and paste values only to the cell you want the answer to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy4Vm.png)
3: find and replace the additional character with nothing (blank replace box). It helps in this example to search by columns.
[find and replace the additional character with nothing (blank replace box). It helps in this example to search by columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztcqo.png)

returns the result of below image.
[final file with calculations in column A and answers in column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I5BZ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).